# my iPhone is show only white screen and black apple after erase on icloud

Tags: email

I saw on some website if forgot restriction pass code erase the phone so I do it then my phone show only white screen and black apple for along time till now what should I do

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying in the body. Can you rephrase it to clarify what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your phone is not turning back on, if so then just do this.

Hold the Power Button (3 secs)

Continue holding the power button and also hold the home button (15 secs)

Release the power button while continuing to hold the home button (10 secs)

Your device should prompt with the "Connect to iTunes Screen"

From here just set up your iPhone as new or restore a previous back up.

Try this a few times just to make sure you did it right, however if this does not work then be sure to take it to the apple store.